# Como usar o SharedPreferencesdo Android? Consigo escolher varios nomes de arquivos?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Eu estou aprendendo a usar o android fazendo uma aplicação de exemplo com varios tipos de funções do Android Studio.
No momento tenho uma lista apresentada em um ListView e gostaria de salva-la. Eu uso o SharedPreferences e funciona bem: salvo e consigo ler o arquivo depois no proprio ListView.
Gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de salvar varios arquivos do mesmo tipo, com o filename sendo a data (por exemplo), e depois para abrir deixar o usuario escolher qual ele quer. Não sei se tenho que trocar para o internal storage ou se da no SharedFiles.
Obrigada
M.Lagua

Comment: Procure deixar pelo menos um trecho do código do que você mencionou que fez e está funcionando. Assim as pessoas poderão te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer o seguinte:

```
 public static void saveMyPlace(Context context, MyPlace myPlaces) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PLACES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ArrayList<MyPlace> mp = getMyPlaces(context);
        if (mp == null)
            mp = new ArrayList<>();
        mp.add(myPlaces);
        String places = new Gson().toJson(mp);
        prefs.edit().putString(Constants.MY_PLACES, places).apply();
    }

    public static ArrayList<MyPlace> getMyPlaces(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PLACES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String myPlaces = prefs.getString(Constants.MY_PLACES, "");
        return new Gson().fromJson(myPlaces, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyPlace>>() {
        }.getType());
    }
```

Substitua `MyPlaces` pela classe que representa os dados que você precisa

Esta é a classe **Myplace**:

```
public class MyPlace implements Serializable {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String city;
    private Date date;
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyPlace{" +
                "latitude=" + latitude +
                ", longitude=" + longitude +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```